# Java / Web: I force 'Secure' flag on cookies however they still work when HTTP is used. Why?

Tags: java, security, cookies, https

I added 'secure' tag to my session-config in web.xml

```
<session-config>
  <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
  <cookie-config>
    <secure>true</secure>
  </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

So it forces all cookies created by the server to be used ONLY in secure connection (HTTPS). 
Yet these cookies still work if I open my web app using HTTP protocol. 
While using HTTP Firebug shows that 'Secure' flag was set on cookies that were placed by the server (I'm not talking about the ones that were created by JavaScript).

THE PROBLEM: 
In my understanding if I force all server cookies to be secure they should not be used on HTTP at all. So I shouldn't be able to log into my app or do anything that requires session. Yet application still works via HTTP with NO PROBLEM at all...

Where am I wrong?

Comment: can you clear all of your browser cookies for your web app domain and when you make a request to your web app over https you get a cookie which has secure flag true and now if you open firebug network tab and make request to your web app over http you see the same cookie being sent ?

Comment: yes, you're right, these secure cookies were not added to request headers when using HTTP. I had bug in my code and it used userid instead of session so that's why my app would still work. Thank a lot!

Comment: You should answer your question by yourself for other's reference if you think it could happen with other developer